# Numpy random choice biased towards first elements

Tags: numpy, random

I have three lists of dates `(x1,x2,x3)`. Each list is equal to the previous plus a new element:

```
x1=['2005-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2006-04-30', '2006-07-31', '2006-10-31', '2007-01-31', '2007-04-30', '2007-07-31', '2007-10-31', '2008-01-31', '2008-04-30', '2008-07-31', '2008-10-31', '2009-01-31', '2009-04-30', '2009-07-31', '2009-10-31', '2010-01-31', '2010-04-30', '2010-07-31', '2010-10-31', '2011-01-31', '2011-04-30', '2011-07-31', '2011-10-31', '2012-01-31', '2012-04-30', '2012-07-31', '2012-10-31', '2013-01-31', '2013-04-30', '2013-07-31', '2013-10-31', '2014-01-31', '2014-04-30', '2014-07-31', '2014-10-31', '2015-01-31', '2015-04-30', '2015-07-31', '2015-10-31', '2016-01-31']

x2=['2005-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2006-04-30', '2006-07-31', '2006-10-31', '2007-01-31', '2007-04-30', '2007-07-31', '2007-10-31', '2008-01-31', '2008-04-30', '2008-07-31', '2008-10-31', '2009-01-31', '2009-04-30', '2009-07-31', '2009-10-31', '2010-01-31', '2010-04-30', '2010-07-31', '2010-10-31', '2011-01-31', '2011-04-30', '2011-07-31', '2011-10-31', '2012-01-31', '2012-04-30', '2012-07-31', '2012-10-31', '2013-01-31', '2013-04-30', '2013-07-31', '2013-10-31', '2014-01-31', '2014-04-30', '2014-07-31', '2014-10-31', '2015-01-31', '2015-04-30', '2015-07-31', '2015-10-31', '2016-01-31', '2016-04-30']

x3=['2005-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2006-04-30', '2006-07-31', '2006-10-31', '2007-01-31', '2007-04-30', '2007-07-31', '2007-10-31', '2008-01-31', '2008-04-30', '2008-07-31', '2008-10-31', '2009-01-31', '2009-04-30', '2009-07-31', '2009-10-31', '2010-01-31', '2010-04-30', '2010-07-31', '2010-10-31', '2011-01-31', '2011-04-30', '2011-07-31', '2011-10-31', '2012-01-31', '2012-04-30', '2012-07-31', '2012-10-31', '2013-01-31', '2013-04-30', '2013-07-31', '2013-10-31', '2014-01-31', '2014-04-30', '2014-07-31', '2014-10-31', '2015-01-31', '2015-04-30', '2015-07-31', '2015-10-31', '2016-01-31', '2016-04-30','2016-07-31']
```

I was surprised by the fact that taking a random sample of length `len(x1)` from any of the above returns identical results.

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.choice(x1,len(x1),replace=True)
array(['2005-10-31', '2006-07-31', '2006-07-31', '2015-07-31',
       '2008-01-31', '2010-07-31', '2011-01-31', '2014-10-31',
       '2011-07-31', '2007-04-30', '2011-10-31', '2011-10-31',
       '2008-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2015-04-30', '2015-07-31',
       '2011-07-31', '2011-10-31', '2010-01-31', '2015-01-31',
       '2012-01-31', '2009-01-31', '2007-10-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2010-10-31', '2009-10-31', '2007-01-31', '2009-07-31',
       '2005-10-31', '2010-04-30', '2014-07-31', '2011-10-31',
       '2013-01-31', '2010-07-31', '2010-07-31', '2009-04-30',
       '2015-07-31', '2013-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2013-10-31', '2013-07-31'], dtype='<U10')
```

The only difference in the following is selecting from `x2`. Even though this list has one additional element, the result is exactly the same:

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.choice(x2,len(x1),replace=True)
array(['2005-10-31', '2006-07-31', '2006-07-31', '2015-07-31',
       '2008-01-31', '2010-07-31', '2011-01-31', '2014-10-31',
       '2011-07-31', '2007-04-30', '2011-10-31', '2011-10-31',
       '2008-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2015-04-30', '2015-07-31',
       '2011-07-31', '2011-10-31', '2010-01-31', '2015-01-31',
       '2012-01-31', '2009-01-31', '2007-10-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2010-10-31', '2009-10-31', '2007-01-31', '2009-07-31',
       '2005-10-31', '2010-04-30', '2014-07-31', '2011-10-31',
       '2013-01-31', '2010-07-31', '2010-07-31', '2009-04-30',
       '2015-07-31', '2013-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2013-10-31', '2013-07-31'], dtype='<U10')
```

And the same for selecting from `x3`, which has two additional elements:

```
np.random.seed(0)
np.random.choice(x3,len(x1),replace=True)
array(['2005-10-31', '2006-07-31', '2006-07-31', '2015-07-31',
       '2008-01-31', '2010-07-31', '2011-01-31', '2014-10-31',
       '2011-07-31', '2007-04-30', '2011-10-31', '2011-10-31',
       '2008-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2015-04-30', '2015-07-31',
       '2011-07-31', '2011-10-31', '2010-01-31', '2015-01-31',
       '2012-01-31', '2009-01-31', '2007-10-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2010-10-31', '2009-10-31', '2007-01-31', '2009-07-31',
       '2005-10-31', '2010-04-30', '2014-07-31', '2011-10-31',
       '2013-01-31', '2010-07-31', '2010-07-31', '2009-04-30',
       '2015-07-31', '2013-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2013-10-31', '2013-07-31'], dtype='<U10')
```

Does this means that when sampling with replacement and the sample size `(len(x1))` is smaller than the input size (`len(x2)` or `len(x3)`), the algorithm is biased towards selecting the first `len(x1)` elements?

**Update**

So I tried something similar with a different seed (1), and it seems that the problem exists partially, as the first k=19 elements are surprisingly the same:

```
np.random.seed(1)
np.random.choice(x1,len(x1),replace=True)
array(['2015-01-31', '2008-10-31', '2007-10-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2008-07-31', '2007-01-31', '2009-07-31', '2005-10-31',
       '2009-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2008-10-31', '2007-07-31',
       '2007-04-30', '2012-01-31', '2010-10-31', '2015-01-31',
       '2010-04-30', '2010-10-31', '2008-07-31', '2012-10-31',
       '2013-01-31', '2009-04-30', '2006-10-31', '2011-07-31',
       '2011-07-31', '2016-01-31', '2013-04-30', '2013-10-31',
       '2011-04-30', '2009-01-31', '2016-01-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2007-07-31', '2011-04-30', '2006-01-31', '2005-10-31',
       '2010-01-31', '2007-10-31', '2011-10-31', '2009-01-31',
       '2007-10-31', '2013-04-30'], dtype='<U10')

np.random.seed(1)
np.random.choice(x2,len(x1),replace=True)
array(['2015-01-31', '2008-10-31', '2007-10-31', '2008-01-31',
       '2008-07-31', '2007-01-31', '2009-07-31', '2005-10-31',
       '2009-10-31', '2006-01-31', '2008-10-31', '2007-07-31',
       '2007-04-30', '2012-01-31', '2010-10-31', '2015-01-31',
       '2010-04-30', '2010-10-31', '2008-07-31', '2016-04-30',
       '2012-10-31', '2013-01-31', '2009-04-30', '2006-10-31',
       '2011-07-31', '2011-07-31', '2016-01-31', '2013-04-30',
       '2013-10-31', '2011-04-30', '2009-01-31', '2016-01-31',
       '2008-01-31', '2007-07-31', '2011-04-30', '2006-01-31',
       '2005-10-31', '2010-01-31', '2007-10-31', '2011-10-31',
       '2009-01-31', '2016-04-30'], dtype='<U10')
```

Answer (score 1):

In computer science random number generators are in fact pseudo-random number generators. They make random number in a statistical sense, but they are not really random. To make they behaviour repeteable you can set a starting value - a seed, and then the generator will always generate the same sequence of numbers. (Which still are random in a statistical sense.)

In each of the examples you "reset" the random number generator using `np.random.seed(0)` and additionally in each example you request to generate `len(x1)` numbers.

Remove `np.random.seed(0)` or place `np.random.seed(0)` only before first example and it will work "randomly".

**EDIT**: In fact such behaviour should not occur, however it seems like a coincidence not a bug, a flaw rather. Possibly a random number generator is generating the values subsequently until the `len(x1)` is reached. Since the values `len(x1)` (42), `len(x2)` (43), `len(x3)` (44) are very similar (they differ by one) it is quite possible that the same indexes will be drawn. However, such situation does not occur for list lengths equal to 43, 44 and 45 elements.

Comment: That is perfectly logical considering the same input x1. The issue is that a different input is given in each example, such as x2 and x3. Can you comment on that?

Comment: Apart from last elements `x1`, `x2`,`x3` are identical. First of them is the shortest. So in each case the same sequence of indexes is drawn. The range of indexes is from 0 to `len(x1)`. After indexes had been drawn the elements of the array are chosen.

Comment: "The range of indexes is from 0 to len(x1)":
The range of indexes should be equal to the length of the input list, which is different for each example.  In every case, len(x1) is just the number of elements to sample. Is that not correct?

Comment: Oh! Sure! You are absolutely right. It must be a bug then. I took a look into the source code and haven't found an error in Python code. It must be a bug somewhere at C level routines: `_rand_int64`, etc. I am not familiar with this part of the code. Strangely such situation takes place only for bigger arrays. In case of 3-5 element lists it does not happen. On the other hand, if the function draws the numbers subsequently and uses the bit shifting it is quite possible that the same values might occur.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is best answered that this is due to an artefact of how Numpy draws bounded integers, i.e. values in `[0, n]`.

Firstly your seed values (`0` and `1`) are almost exactly the same, differing by only a single bit — I'd suggest making a more significant change.  These aren't passed through any cryptographic primitives hence the seed bits won't be [well mixed into the output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect).

Secondly, the [legacy RNG](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/legacy.html) you're using only produces integer sized outputs (32 bit values) and these need to be transformed into bounded values.  What you're seeing is an artefact of this process.  I'd suggest just passing an integer to `np.random.choice` to see what's going on here.

If you want a better RNG you might consider using the newer interface:

```
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
rng.choice(n, k, replace=True)
```

which allows newer and better algorithms to be used. Note that the Numpy team has decided that changing the legacy generator isn't worth the effort as it would invalidate too much existing code (e.g. test code that rely on the RNG returning values in the same order).

If you want more detail, Melissa O'Neill has a good survey of different ways of [generating bounded integers on her PCG site](https://www.pcg-random.org/posts/bounded-rands.html).  Note that this is the same PCG currently used by by Numpy's `default_rng`.